# how to change specific items in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to remove textview from specific items in recycler view. I wrote the below code to do that

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Myholder holder, final int possion) {
        final String n = names.get(possion);
        if(possion==3){
        holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);}}
```

but this changes all items and i want to make gone only position number 3 item view.
this is my view holder

```
public static class Myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        public Myholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textfolder);
        }
    }
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always remember that `RecyclerView` *recycles* view holders. That is, the same `ViewHolder` instance will be re-used for different views. This means that it is almost always a bad idea to have an `if` statement that modifies a view withouth having a corresponding `else`.

So, try this instead:

```
if (possion == 3) {
    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Note also that just checking the `position` argument is not necessarily a good idea. If you use `notifyItemInserted()` or `notifyItemRemoved()`, this can lead to problems.

It would be better to set something about the item at that position to indicate that its text should not be shown.

Comment: Try specifying on your item.xml that textfolder -> android:visibility="visible" so that's the default value

Comment: Also, on your adapter have you overrided getItemId(int position) and getItemViewType(int position)  ?

Comment: @siavashhosseini but this answer should have fixed the issue, Did not it fix ?